# jQuery how to copy row input value into hidden field?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple requirement and i am struggling with it.

There are multiple rows with input and hidden fields when the user clicks the row button, I need to take the value from the input and set the current row hidden field with it.

So:

```
 if user clicks on row 1 - take input text from row 1 and set it in hidden of row 1
 if user clicks on row 2 - take input text from row 2 and set it in hidden of row 2   
 ...
 if user clicks on row n - take input text from row n and set it in hidden of row n
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".copyVal").click(function() {
       var inputValue = $(this).parent().find("input.inpClass:text").val();
       console.log("Input Value is:" + inputValue);
          
       var currentRowHidden = $(this).parent().find("[id^='hidden_']");
       console.log("current hidden id to set is:" + $(currentRowHidden).attr('id') );
       $(currentRowHidden).val(inputValue);          
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


ROW1:
<div class="form-group row">
  <input type="text" class="inpClass" value="ROW1"/>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button class="btn btn-primary copyVal"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt">Button1</i></button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden"  id="hidden_1" name="hidden_1" value="">
</div>


ROW2:
<div class="form-group row">
   <input type="text" class="inpClass" value="ROW2"/>
   <div class="col-xs-1">
     <button class="btn btn-primary  copyVal"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt">Button2</i></button>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden"  id="hidden_2" name="hidden_2" value="">
</div>
  
ROW3:
<div class="form-group row">
  <input type="text" class="inpClass" value="ROW3"/>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
     <button class="btn btn-primary  copyVal"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt">Button3</i></button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden"  id="hidden_3" name="hidden_3" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `.parent()` selector which will return the immediate parent, and you do not have any hidden fields in immediate parent of `button`.

You need to use `.parents()` selector to search through the ancestor elements, not just immediate parent.

Here is Documentation: [.parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) [.parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

I have changed your code snippet as below to use `.parents` selector:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".copyVal").click(function() {
          var inputValue = $(this).parents("div.row").find("input.inpClass:text").val();
          console.log("Input Value is:" + inputValue);
          
          var currentRowHidden = $(this).parents("div.row").find("[id^='hidden_']");
          console.log("current hidden id to set is:" + $(currentRowHidden).attr('id') );
          $(currentRowHidden).val(inputValue);          
          
          }
         );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


ROW1:
<div class="form-group row">
          <input type="text" class="inpClass" value="ROW1"/>
          <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button class="btn btn-primary copyVal">
      <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt">Button1</i>
        </button>
    </div>
          <input type="hidden"  id="hidden_1" name="hidden_1" value="">
    </div>

ROW2:
<div class="form-group row">
          <input type="text" class="inpClass" value="ROW2"/>
          <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button class="btn btn-primary  copyVal">
     <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt">Button1</i>
    </button>
       </div>
          <input type="hidden"  id="hidden_2" name="hidden_2" value="">
    </div>

ROW3:
 <div class="form-group row">
          <input type="text" class="inpClass" value="ROW3"/>
          <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button class="btn btn-primary  copyVal">
     <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt">Button1</i>
    </button>
    </div>
          <input type="hidden"  id="hidden_3" name="hidden_3" value="">
    </div>
```